# Python read_csv - ParserError: Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, pandas

I understand why I get this error when trying to `df = pd.read_csv(file)`  :

`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 14 fields in line 7, saw 30`

When it reads in the csv, it sees 14 strings/columns in the first row, based on the first row of the csv calls it the headers (which is what I want).

However, those columns are extended further, down the rows (specifially when it gets to row 7).

I can find solutions that will read it in by skipping those rows 1-6, but I don't want that. I still want the whole csv to be read, but instead of the header being 14 columns, how can I tell it make the header 30 columns, and if there is no text/string, just leave the column as a "", or null, or some random numbering. In other words, I don't care what it's named, I just need the space holder so it can parse after row 6.

I'm wondering is there a way to read in the csv, and explicitly say there are 30 columns but have not found a solution.

Comment: what you have used as delimeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can throw some random solutions that I think should work.

1) Set Header=None and give columns names in 'Name' attribute of read_csv.

```
 df=pd.read_csv(file, header=None, namees = [field1, field2, ...., field 30])
```

PS. This will work if your CSV doesn't have a header already.

2) Secondly you can try using below command (if your csv already has header row)

```
df=pd.read_csv(file, usecols=[0,1,2,...,30])
```

Let me know if this works out for you.

Thanks,

Rohan Hodarkar

Comment: The first solution is a good one.  You can pass `skiprows=1` to ignore the header in the file, so that it doesn't end up in the DataFrame.  I think the second solution doesn't work.

Comment: I've done the skiprows before. But in this particular case, I would be skipping rows 1-6, and I don't want to skip those, I need those included.

I've tried use cols, but it doesn't have a column beyond the 14th. That's why I was wondering if I could explicitly tell it, there are columns after 14, just call then null. The first solution works though. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

what about trying, to be noted `error_bad_lines=False` will cause the offending lines to be skipped

```
data = pd.read_csv('File_path', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Just few more collectives answers..

It might be an issue with the delimiters in your data the first row,
To solve it, try specifying the sep and/or header arguments when calling read_csv. For instance,

```
df = pandas.read_csv('File_path', sep='delimiter', header=None)
```

In the code above, sep defines your delimiter and header=None tells pandas that your source data has no row for headers / column titles. Here Documenet says: "If file contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None". In this instance, pandas automatically creates whole-number indices for each field {0,1,2,...}.

According to the docs, the delimiter thing should not be an issue. The docs say that "if sep is None [not specified], will try to automatically determine this." I however have not had good luck with this, including instances with obvious delimiters.

This might be an issue of delimiter, as most of the csv CSV are got create using sep='/t' so try to read_csv using the tab character (\t) using separator /t. so, try to open using following code line.

```
data=pd.read_csv("File_path", sep='\t')
```

OR

```
pandas.read_csv('File_path',header=None,sep=', ')
```